# extract query parameters from endpoint and append to SQL Query

Tags: mule

I have an endpoint like this 
api.com/users?id=id1,id2,id3,id4,id5...id500

1. I need to extract the query parameters from the endpoint i.e id1,id2
   etc...
2. Then i need to append the parameters to an SQL statement like this

   select column1,column2 
       from my_table 
       where column3 like 'id1%'; 
       or column3 like 'id2%' 
       or column3 like 'id4%' ..

.

Any ideas on how do i go about accomplishing this ? 
i am pretty new to Mulesoft.

```
#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.size()] gives me the number of values in the parameters

#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.id] perhaps would give me an collection or arrayList ?
```

I would want to loop over each item of the arrayList and from a string like
where column3 like arrayList[0] + '%'

but i am clueless on how to achieve this and append this to the SQL Querythat i dispatch to the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Get the value of query string and setpayload.

```
<set-payload value="id1,id2,id3,id4,id5" doc:name="Set Sample Payload"/>
```

2.Create StringBuffer

```
  <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[StringBuffer sb = new 
    StringBuffer();
    flowVars.stBuffer=sb;
    ]]></expression-component>
```

3.Split the payload

```
 <expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload.split(&quot;,&quot;)]" 
    doc:name="Split String"/>
```

4.Construct sql in the for loop by appending values in string buffer

```
<foreach collection="#[payload]" doc:name="For Each">
           Construct sql here using string buffer
   </foreach>
```

Reference: [Splitting a comma-separated string and saving to database without DataWeave in Mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907704/splitting-a-comma-separated-string-and-saving-to-database-without-dataweave-in-m)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the query parameter as application/json and pass the single value in this in Json format with field and values which can be easily extracted in you API.